# Perl - How to search the iteration of a line (from the same text) in a text

Tags: perl, file

[SOLVED]
sorry in advance for my bad code (I'm new to Perl). 
I need to write a script that searches a certain line of text in a file (it must contain the words "authentication failure" and a username in the form "user=username") and looks for the possible iterations of lines containing the same username and "authentication failure" which was recorded on the same day. The day and month are the first two words of each line of the text I'm analyzing. Each line is therefore something like:

```
"Jun 24 bla bla bla authentication failure bla bla bla user=mickey_mouse"
```

Anyway regardless of my goal, I'm sure that the problem is my inexperience with Perl. So please just give a look at my code and tell me if there's something not ok.

Here's the code I've written 'till now

```
#!usr/bin/perl
if (!defined($ARGV[0]) or !defined($ARGV[1])) {
    die "\nMissing arguments.\n";
}
open(FILE,$ARGV[0]) or die "Cannot open log file";
open(FILE1,$ARGV[0]) or die "Cannot open log file";

foreach $line(<FILE>) {
    chomp;
    if($line=~/authentication failure/ and $line=~/ user=/) {
        $count = 0;
        @chops = split("=", $line);
        $currentUser = $chops[-1];
        chomp($currentUser);
        @chops1 = split(" ", $line);
        $currentDate = $chops1[0]." ".$chops1[1];
        chomp($currentDate);
        print "\nUSER: $currentUser DATE: $currentDate\n";
        foreach $line1(<FILE1>) {
            chomp;
            if(index($line1, $currentUser) != -1 and 
               index($line1, $currentDate) != -1 and 
               $line1 =~ /authentication failure/) {
                $count++;
                print $count;
                if(count>=2) {
                    push($currentUser,@authenticFails);
                    last;
                }   
            }
        }
    }

}

print @authenticFails;

close(FILE);
close(FILE1);
```

[SOLVED] Thanks for the answer and suggestions to sputnick. Anyway I figured out what my problem was. I just needed to write the second open(ARGV[0]) thing inside the nested -for- block (and not before both the fors) and close it before exiting. This is the only way to restart iterating on each line of the file for each current line that I'm analyzing with the first -for- block.

Thanks again guys.

Comment: Why don't you use grep -i -r "authentication failure" filename.txt and similarly for username

Comment: `push($currentUser,@authenticFails)` -- mixed up the order of the arguments. This is a fatal error, and cannot be in the code you ran. Never, ever post code that is not the actual code you are running. It just wastes our time.

Comment: Yeah, found out that too. Thanks though. :)

Comment: Why are you checking each line in `FILE` against each line in `FILE1`? Also, won't this code cause partial matches, such as matching `Jun 1` with `Jun 10`, and `user=foo` against `foobar`? User `cat` will receive a whole lot of authentication failure matches, since that name matches `authentiCATion`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I would do using the *diamond operator* `<>` and a hash to count the occurrences :

```
use Modern::Perl; # enable strictures and features like "say"

my %hash;
# looping line by lines over the files
while (my $line = <ARGV>) {
    if ($line =~ /^(\w+\s+\d+)\s+.*?authentication\s+failure.*?user=(.*)/) {
        $hash{"$2|$1"}++;
    }
}
foreach my $key (keys %hash) {
    my ($user, $day) = split /\|/, $key;
    say "$hash{$key} auth failures for $user on $day";
}
```

#### Output

```
3 auth failures for mickey_mouse on  Jun 24
1 auth failures for mickey_mouse on  Jun 23
1 auth failures for xxx on  Jun 21
```

#### Notes

- always put `use strict; use warnings;` or `use Modern::Perl`
- if you open files, do it the right way : `open my $fh, "<", "file" or die $!` and you can even omit the `or die` by adding `use autodie` like Dadid W suggest.

Comment: Why not add `use autodie;`?